# What unicode character groups should we limit the user to, to create Beautiful URLs?

Tags: php, url, unicode, encoding

I recently started looking at adding untrusted usernames in prettied urls, eg:

```
mysite.com/
mysite.com/user/sarah
mysite.com/user/sarah/article/my-home-in-brugge
mysite.com/user/sarah/settings
etc..
```

Note the username 'sarah' and the article name 'my-home-in-brugge'.

What I would like to achieve, is that someone could just copy-paste the following url somewhere:

```
(1)
mysite.com/user/Björk Guðmundsdóttir/articles
mysite.com/user/毛泽东/posts
```

...and it would just be very clear, before clicking on the link, what to expect to see. The following two exact same urls, where the usernames have been encoded using PHP `rawurlencode()` (considered the proper way of doing this):

```
(2)
mysite.com/user/Bj%C3%B6rk%20Gu%C3%B0mundsd%C3%B3ttir/articles
mysite.com/user/%E6%AF%9B%E6%B3%BD%E4%B8%9C/posts
```

...are a lot less clear.

There are three ways to securely (to some level of guarantee) pass an untrusted name containing readable utf8 characters into a url path as a directory:

A. You reparse the string into allowable characters whilst still keeping it uniquely associated in your database to that user, eg:

```
    (3)
    mysite.com/user/bjork-guomundsdottir/articles
    mysite.com/user/mao-ze-dong12/posts
```

B. You limit the user's input at string creation time to acceptable characters for url passing (you ask eg. for alphanumeric characters only):

```
    (4)
    mysite.com/user/bjorkguomundsdottir/articles
    mysite.com/user/maozedong12/posts

using eg. a regex check (for simplicity sake)

    if(!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}\p{P}\p{Zs}\p{Sm}\p{Sc}]+$/u', trim($sUserInput))) {
      //...
    }
```

C. You escape them in full using PHP `rawurlencode()`, and get the ugly output as in (2).

**Question:**

I want to focus on B, and push this as far as is possible within KNOWN errors/concerns, until we get the beautiful urls as in (1). I found out that passing many unicode characters in urls is possible in modern browsers. Modern browsers automatically convert unicode characters or non-url parseable characters into encoded characters, allowing the user to Eg. Copy paste the nice-looking unicode urls as in (1), and the browser will get the actual final url right.

For some characters, the browser will not get it right without encoding: Eg. ?, #, / or \ will definitely and clearly break the url.

So: Which characters in the (non-alphanumeric) ascii range can we allow at creation time, accross the entire unicode spectrum, to be injected into a url without escaping? Or better: Which groups of Unicode characters can we allow? Which characters are definitely always blacklisted ? There will be special cases: Spaces look fine, except at the end of the string, otherwise they could be mis-selected. Is there a reference out there, that shows which browsers interprete which unicode character ranges ok?

PS: I am very well aware that using improperly encoded strings in urls will almost *never* provide a security guarantee. This question is certainly not recommended practice, but I do not see the difference of asking this question, and the done-so-often matter of copy-pasting a url from a website and pasting it into the browser, without thinking it through whether that url was correctly encoded or not (the novice user wouldn't). Has someone looked at this before, and what was their code (regex, conditions, if-statement..) solution?